# Schema org.gnome.Empathy not installed

Tags: gnome, empathy, powerpc

Having recently installed Ubuntu on my iBook G4 (yup, power PC style), I click on all available buttons to see what happens (as Ubuntu is full of nice buttons, really).

Strangely, when clicking the mail button on menu bar, nothing happens. After having found it in fact starts [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy), I launched it from terminal, and got the following :

```
   GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.Empathy' is not installed

   aborting...
   aborted
```

What can I do to fix that and make Empathy work correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a known issue with the PowerPC build of Empathy. There isn't a fix available yet but if you report a bug to the powerpc publishers/developers then they can have a look at the problem.

I suspect the schema has been compiled for x86 and somehow sneaked into the ppc distribution. But I haven't dug much into it.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/empathy/

Comment: Have you got any documentation on how to do such a bug report ?

Comment: Here you go: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Thanks, bug has been filled as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/674374